# php keyworks search do not works

Tags: php

i want to retrieve data in database by using search engine i create.

it pass the search keywords from testseach.php to searchTitle.php.

here is my code for test seach.php

```
    >!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head><title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form action="searchTitle.php" method="GET" class="formright">
                        <input  type="text" name="keywords" placeholder="Search">
                        <input type="submit" value="search">                                        
                        </form> 
    </body>
    </html>
```

here is my searchtitle.php which pass the keywords from testsearch.

```
<? php
    require_once 'database_conn.php'

    //collect search title
    if(isset($_GET['keywords'])){

        $searchq = $_GET['keywords'];
        $searchq = preg_replace("#[^a-z]#i" , "", $searchq);

        $query = mysql_query("SELECT eventTitle FROM te_events where eventTitle LIKE '%searchq%'") or die("could not search!");

        $count = mysqli_num_rows($query);

        if($count==0){
            echo "<p>There was no search result!</p>\n";
        }
        else{
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
                $title = $row['eventTitle'];
                $id    = $row['eventID'];

                echo "<p>$title</p>\n";
            }
    }
    }
?>
```

however, it shows this error

> There was no search result! \n"; } else{ while ($row =
>   mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){ $title = $row['eventTitle']; $id =
>   $row['eventID']; echo " $title
>
> \n"; } } } ?>

i pretty sure that my database connection is working and i don't see any typo in my code.

can anyone tell me what's is my problem?

Comment: That implies PHP isn't even running. But you have numerous basic mistakes in the code you've provided e.g. `<? php` which I would expect to syntax error, making it almost certain you don't have PHP set up properly.

Answer (score 1):

There are some mistake

1)$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `countries`",$connection) or die("could not search!");

In mysql_query you add connection variable

please refer syntax as per php documentation

2)  You use **$count = mysqli_num_rows($query);** for get number of raw but you use mysql_num_rows instead of mysqli_num_rows

**OR**

Please check php version and that compatible with mysql or mysqli 
please check it also because that may cause that type of issue also

this answer may be help you.